# Find key that matches value in zsh associative array?

Tags: zsh, associative-array

In a regular array, I can use `(i)` or `(I)` to search for the index of entries matching a given value (first match from the start or end of the array, respectively):

```
list=(foo bar baz)
echo $list[(i)bar]
# => 2
```

This doesn't work for associative arrays, to get (one of) the key(s) where a value is found:

```
declare -A hash=([foo]=bar [baz]=zoo)
echo $hash[(i)bar]
# => no output
```

Is there another mechanism for doing this, other than manually looping through?

Comment: I assume you don't want to keep an explicit reverse mapping.

Comment: I mean, that's fine, too, and beats having to do the loop. I'm used to bash which doesn't even have anything like `[(i)]`. But since zsh does have that I was kind of surprised it's not there for the associative case.

Comment: I was sort of hoping that I could do `${(vk)}` instead of `$((kv)}` and get the pairs the other way around, but no such luck. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(r)` subscript flag combined with the `(k)` parameter flag should give you
what you want:

```
declare -A hash=([foo]=bar [baz]=zoo)
echo ${(k)hash[(r)bar]}
# => foo
```

The man page section on the `(r)` subscript flag only talks about returning
values and ignores this usage, so it's hard to find.

Comment: I had actually entirely missed the documentation on subscript flags, since they're off in zshparam and not next to the expansion flags in zshexpn. I only learned about `(i)` from examples. But I have now found them, and I see that, in fact, `(i)` is described as a variation on `(r)`!  Right in front of me if only I'd looked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something completely disgusting:

```
% declare -A hash=([foo]=bar [baz]=zoo)
% echo ${${(kA)hash}[${${(A)hash[@]}[(i)bar]}]}
foo
```

Basically, it consists of two parts:

1. `${${(A)hash[@]}[(i)bar]}`, which computes the index of `bar` in an anonymous array consisting of the values of the associative array.
2. `${${(kA)hash}[...]}`, which indexes the anonymous array consisting of the *keys* of the associative array using the numerical index computed by the previous expansion.

I'm not aware of a short equivalent to the `I` flag, and I too am surprised that the seemingly obvious extension to associative arrays doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like zsh has enough context to know to treat that first subexpression as an array, so you can do without the first `A` flag: `${${(k)hash}[${${(A)hash}[(i)bar]}]}`  works. Still a darn lot of braces, though. Thanks!